# Fractal sequence in R

Tags: r, sequence

I am looking for a function to create fractal sequences in R, and I wondered if there are convenience functions built-in into R to do this.

Let's say, I would like to create the following fractal sequence:

`1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5`

**Code**

I could write a simple function to create the fractal sequence:

```
library(purrr)

x <- function(x){
  map(seq(1,x, 1), ~seq(1,.x, 1)) %>% unlist
}

x(5)
#>  [1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5
```

**Question**

Are there easier ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sequence` function  in base R :

```
x <- function(x){
    sequence(seq_len(x))
} 

x(5)
#[1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5
```